# matplotlib axes enter exit event not working?

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, axes

This code from matplotlib examples does not work as I expected. Entering/exiting axes does not trigger any event. Only by clicking
inside/outside the axes you get enter/leave events. Is that the intended behavior? Python3, OSX.

```
"""
Illustrate the figure and axes enter and leave events by changing the
frame colors on enter and leave
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def enter_axes(event):
    print('enter_axes', event.inaxes)
    event.inaxes.patch.set_facecolor('yellow')
    event.canvas.draw()


def leave_axes(event):
    print('leave_axes', event.inaxes)
    event.inaxes.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    event.canvas.draw()


def enter_figure(event):
    print('enter_figure', event.canvas.figure)
    event.canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor('red')
    event.canvas.draw()


def leave_figure(event):
    print('leave_figure', event.canvas.figure)
    event.canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor('grey')
    event.canvas.draw()

fig1, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig1.suptitle('mouse hover over figure or axes to trigger events')

fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event', enter_figure)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_leave_event', leave_figure)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', enter_axes)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', leave_axes)

fig2, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig2.suptitle('mouse hover over figure or axes to trigger events')

fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event', enter_figure)
fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_leave_event', leave_figure)
fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', enter_axes)
fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', leave_axes)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This works fine under windows. Maybe its a Mac problem. You could try a different backend: `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`.

Comment: Yeah, it works with TkAgg.